# How to open inbuilt open google map on button click

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

Please suggest me i am new in android How to Open an inbuilt Google map on button click in android i am having one image button.
**How to open inbuilt open google map on button click**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May this helps you.

**Example:-**

```
btn_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=");
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

past this code in onclick listner

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + sourceLatitude + "," + sourceLongitude + "&daddr=" + destinationLatitude + "," + destinationLongitude;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what about sourceLatitude  and Longitude its showing error @sagar patel

Comment: add location latitude and longtitude

Comment: How sir i dont know

Comment: if you need to get current position then use Locationmanager class.otherwise direct set Latitude and Longtitude of your address

Comment: http://mygeoposition.com/       put your address in this link and get lat and long

Comment: sir we have to declare any variable after getting location

Comment: Like String sourceLatitude

Comment: you also use direct without declare variable

Comment: i want to show only current location but it also asking for destination

Comment: String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);

Comment: using Above code you can create uri  without destination

Comment: i am getting error

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %f can't format java.lang.String arguments

Comment: you can try to open the built-in application Android Maps by using the Intent.setClassName method.

                   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:37.827500,-122.481670"));
i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + sourceLatitude + "," + sourceLongitude + "&daddr=" + destinationLatitude + "," + destinationLongitude;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
```

intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

startActivity(intent);